# Converting number strings to Values in Excel

Tags: excel

After scraping a website I ended up with values with dashes in the data like 7-6, 12-5, 3-12. I was able to separate the data into to their own columns making the previous examples being 7, 6  , 12,5   3,12, but the data has turned from values that you can add and subtract to something like a string. Is there a way to make the strings into values.

0        15

1        2

5        6

4   8

3   2

2   1

If i go through each cell and double click the strings it converts to values, but I cant do that to 55000 cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert a text string that represents a number to number format using the `Value()` formula

Example: 
`B1 = Value(A1))`

if `A1 = 15` in text format

Answer (score 0):

You can select the whole columns and convert to number. Go to menu Data > Convert and then, follow the wizard.